# intersection of subgroups containing H and K is {hk}, if one of H or K in a normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given subgroups H, K of a group G, we define $$HK = \bigcap_{H \cup K \subseteq L<G} L$$

I need to prove that if at least one of H, K is normal in G then HK can be written explicitly (i.e., without resorting to an abstract-intersection-type description)
as $HK = \{hk \mid h \in H, k \in K\}$.

I have no clue how to even start dealing with this weird intersection. Can someone help?

Comment: I think that's a terrible way to define $HK$, because it may not be correct if neither group is normal.

Comment: that's true. but it is given that at least one is normal. I still can't see how to prove that.

Comment: By the way, $HK$ is not the Cartesian product unless $H\cap K=\{e\} $.

Comment: that's right, i'll edit the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

With this strange definition of $HK$, you have to prove:

1. Any subgroup $L$ of $G$ which contains $H$ and $K$ contains all elements in $\;\{hk \mid h \in H, k \in K\}$.
2. This set  is a subgroup of $G$. This where one of the subgroups being normal is useful.

Comment: 1. is pretty trivial. But I don't see how 2 concludes the proof, I still need to show that this $\{hk\}$ proven to be a subgroup is the minimal $L$ or something like that, no?

Comment: If this set  is a subgroup of $G$, it is obviously the smallest of the $L$s which contain it!

Comment: it's probably something trivial that I miss, but i don't see why it's obvious...

Comment: That is because it is contained in every subgroup $L$ containing $H$ and $K$, and because by 1., it *is* one of these subgroups.